# Ngx-Translate bug whith other content

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

There is a weird behaviour with Ngx-Translate depends if your using the directive method with other content or not.

According to the [Ngx-Translate documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) the following snippets work perfectly, the translated key is displayed:

```
<el1 [translate]="'I18N.KEY'"></el1>

<el1>{{ 'I18N.KEY' | translate }}
  <el2>other content</el2>
</el1>
```

---

These two snippets are NOT working:

```
<el1 [translate]="'I18N.KEY'">
  <el2>other content</el2>
</el1>

<el1 translate>I18N.KEY
  <el2>other content</el2>
</el1>
```

Results:

1. Displays only the "other content" skipping the translation
2. The translation is not anymore translated on language change

Why ? There is no warning in the documentation about the directive use limitation.

Check it in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/91k00-ngx-translate-bug)

Comment: Very interesting investigation and useful content that should be taken into account for future. What's your question?

Comment: Why don't you just apply the translation to a specific child next to `<el2>other content</el2>` ?

Comment: I'd say it's working as intended. If you require having additional content within the element you should be using the pipe `{{ 'HOME.TEXT' | translate }}` instead of directive.

Comment: @penleychan True that is "working" but nothing specified in documentation, so I supposed that all methods work like a charm...
We replaced all occurences with pipe method, the only one has the expected behaviour. Thx